# RxJS Does Observable empty the data array after onCompleted is called?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I am struggling with RxJS. Some questions about Observable

1. Does Observable empty the data array after onCompleted is called?
2. when I chain two subscribe() method together I got error "subscribe does not exist in type Subscription". Why is that?

   someObs.map(...).subscribe(...).subscribe(...)
3. Is there a way to check an observable data array count without subscribing?
4. If Observable clears the data items after emitting them is there a way to refill new data items into the same observable instance without creating a new one? if yes, how?

Comment: Not sure about the others, but 2 doesn't work because the return of `#subscribe()` is of type `Subscription`, which does not have a method called `#subscribe()`. In order for that to work, `#subscribe()` would have to return the Observable again, which wouldn't really make sense. You should move the `.subscribe()` calls to their own lines, instead of chaining both of them. Oh and for #4, you could use a [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. RxJS is a close cousin of Functional Programming, which means that mutation is generally a big no-no. The whole point of streaming data is to avoid state mutation, which is in many ways the source of many troubles in today's applications.

All Observables do is wrap various data source types so that they emit events through a common interface. Hence `Rx.Observable.fromArray` and `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` both produce Observables with the same semantics, the only difference being the number of events and when those events are produced.

2. `Observables` are lazy, all the fancy method chaining doesn't do anything until the Observable is finally subscribed to. So that `subscribe` is really like saying "execute" or "go", it will allow events to begin moving through the Observable.
3. Not sure what you mean by "Observable data array", see point 1. If you pass an array to an Observable then you should be able to check the size of *that*
4. It doesn't, but yes you can in a sense "refill" an Observable based on an Array by simply resubscribing to it, that will begin the process of sending the events again. As dvlsg mentioned you could also use a `Subject` to explicitly push events to an Observer, but in 99% of the cases its use can and should be avoided because it is being used as a crutch to avoid having to actually be *reactive*

i.e.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray([1, 2, 3, 4]);

//First subscription, prints all of the events from array
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

//Second subscription, prints all the events *again* because
//this is a new subscription occurrence
source.subscribe(y => console.log(y));
```

Comment: paulpdaniels, thanks for the detailed explanation that cleared a lot of the mud in my mind:)

Comment: I have to put in at least a slight disagreement about point #4. I agree that when you *can* avoid using a `Subject` you should, but there are plenty of times where you'll want to subscribe to a long-running set of changes where you need to manually push changes from a source that isn't supported directly by `rxjs`. A `Subject` is probably more closely related to an `EventEmitter` in `nodejs`. I suppose you could argue that you should just use an `EventEmitter` in those cases and subscribe to *that*, though.

Comment: Here is some more [reading](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/howdoi/eventemitter.md) from the rxjs docs.

Comment: Conceptually you are right, `Subjects` are similar to `EventEmitters` in their semantics and one certainly _can_ use them, however, whenever one says "manually push changes" that usually means you haven't actually reached the source of the events. Once you do, 9 out of 10 times it is solvable with one of the factory methods. Subjects are mainly used internally for multi casting behavior, where it can be tightly constrained and its state doesn't bleed all over the place.